# How to tell an event handler method who called it in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to use the same method as an event handler for multiple dropdowns. In order for part of the method to work, they must know who called them - either the name of the dropdown or the title it stores as its first value. I know that I could create an individual method for each one of these dropdowns, but that seems excessive. Is there a way to do something along the lines of

```
OnClick(int indexSelected, string dropdownTitle)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to use the same method as an event handler for multiple
>   dropdowns.

You can pass the `Dropdown` instance as parameter with the help of `delegate`  then compare which one it is by the instance, name or which ever property you prefer.

```
public Dropdown dropdown;

Dropdown otherDropDown;
void OnEnable()
{
    //Register to onValueChanged Events
    dropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { callBack(dropdown); });
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-Register from onValueChanged Events
    dropdown.onValueChanged.RemoveAllListeners();
}

void callBack(Dropdown currentDropdown)
{
    //Compare dropdown by instance?
    if (currentDropdown == otherDropDown)
    {
        int value = currentDropdown.value;
    }

    //Compare dropdown by name
    if (currentDropdown.name == "YourDPName")
    {
        int value = currentDropdown.value;
    }
}
```